# Keep getting an Error while running rubocop with Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci, rubocop

I can't figure out where this error comes from. There are no AlignWith parameter in actual rubocop file. Will appreciate any tips. The error and a copy of rubocop.yml and travis file is below. Thank you.

**Error:** obsolete parameter AlignWith (for Lint/EndAlignment) found in /home/travis/build/firehosefirechess/chess_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/.rubocop.yml
`AlignWith` has been renamed to `EnforcedStyleAlignWith`

**.rubocop.yml**

```
Documentation:

  Enabled: false

EndOfLine:

  Enabled: false

AllCops:

  Include:

    - '**/Rakefile'
    - '**/config.ru'
    - '**/Gemfile'
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'script/**/*'
    - !ruby/regexp /old_and_unused\.rb$/

Lint/EndAlignment:
  EnforcedStyleAlignWith: variable

Style/Encoding:
  Enabled: false

Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 99

Metrics/BlockLength:
  Enabled: false

UnusedBlockArgument:
  Description: 'Checks for unused block arguments.'
  Enabled: false

Style/EmptyLines:
  Enabled: false

Style/TrailingBlankLines:
  Enabled: false

**travis.yml**

language: ruby

cache: bundler

rvm:
- 2.4.1

before_script:

 - bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:seed

script:

- bundle exec rubocop

services:

- postgresql
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look a little closer at the error:

```
Error: obsolete parameter AlignWith (for Lint/EndAlignment) found in /home/travis/build/firehosefirechess/chess_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/.rubocop.yml AlignWith has been renamed to EnforcedStyleAlignWith
```

It's not your app's .rubocop.yml where the error is showing up, it's actually in `chess_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/.rubocop.yml`!

As you probably don't want to be running Rubocop on vendor code, you can resolve this by adding a line to the `Exclude` list in your own config:

`- 'vendor/**/*'`

Comment: Additionally, this has been fixed in the latest `rake`, so if you update your dependencies, that would also work. :-)